# green color success message on MS Teams for messageBack action type in Thumbnail/Hero cards

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

Recently we have started observing a 'green' Success message upon executing a Card action of type 'messageBack' on Teams. See screenshot attached. Looks like this is a new [feature](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/five-new-features-enhancing-adaptive-cards-in-microsoft-teams/) released for Adaptive Cards, however we observe it for messageBack action on Thumbnail / Hero cards as well.

Any input on how this message could be disabled would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever users submit information via Action.Submit or Action.Execute to your bot it will show a success indicator upon completion of the invoke call.
There is no such way to disable it. It is by design.

Answer (score 0):

In new versions of MS Teams it will be displayed gray and the texting is improved.

[image: Success bar]